# removing and adding attributes for the second time not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer, the following code doesn't work if its called a second time

```
$(e.target).siblings().prev().removeAttr("checked");
```

Please provide all the help you can.
Thank you.

Comment: Always use `.prop()` for boolean attributes rather than `.attr()`

Answer (score 1):

Removing an attribute using javascript will remove the attribute from the element permanently.

You can use `$(e.target).siblings().prev().prop("checked", false);` instead.  This will only update the element instead of permanently altering it.

Without getting too detailed in an already answered question, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) on the differences between `attr` and `prop` in JQuery.  Notably, the `checked` attribute and property behave in different ways, where the `attr` potentially reflects the default value while the `prop` reflects the current value.  In most cases (since JQuery 1.6), using `.prop()` to manipulate element properties is favored.

Comment: but i can see the property <input class="css-checkbox toggle-checkbox " type="checkbox" checked="checked" > on DOM.

Comment: adding the attribute checked for second time is working fine but remove is not

Comment: Updated the answer with some more information on `attr` vs. `prop`